80's or 90's horror movie with someone eating a beating heart
I can't remember the name of a horror movie from the 80's or early 90's with a scene in the bedroom where some guy is sleeping and blood starts to fill the room, defying gravity (from the ceiling). There is also a scene with a still-beating human heart.
EDIT: I've watched this movie in a theater in 1989 or 1990. Language is English, country probably USA. Main character remembers that someone forced him to eat his father's still-beating hearth (I'm not 100% positive about this).

You'll have to give us a bit more to go on than this.  Country? Language? etc.

Eating a beating heart and blood dripping from the ceiling are both found in Angel Heart (it's from 1987, but was still in theaters in some countries in 1989).

It is Angel Heart (1987).

Harry Angel is a private investigator. He is hired by a man who calls himself Louis Cyphre to track down a singer called Johnny Favorite. But the investigation takes an unexpected and somber turn.

It features scenes where someone eats a beating heart and blood drips from the ceiling. It was still in theaters in some countries in 1989.

You might want to elaborate in which this fits to the details from the question in order to flesh out the answer a little more.

Why don't you let Walt answer the question, since he was the one who knew the movie?

@Cikson Don't forget to approve the answer (by clicking on the check mark).
